# Unable to run flutter project on Android connected with USB

Tags: android, flutter, usb-debugging

I am trying to run my flutter project on Android connected with USB Debugging Enabled , i tried running flutter doctor it saying everything is OK [flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogjjB.png)but while running the project it stucks on gradle task assembling [gradle assembling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD02m.png), also my device is authorised with my PC and all other commands like push pull working fine

**Edit**
running flutter run -v gives an Error

```
[   +6 ms] Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip
```

file

```
[   +2 ms] [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.Retrying to download...
       

[+7209 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: is it your first time?

Comment: Try to Restart your mobile phone

Comment: yes this is my first time and i did tried to restart my device and tried revoking debugging permissions but no effects

Comment: and i am not familiar with flutter projects

Comment: run this command `flutter run -v` ,if you are first time running the flutter project it will take some time @BhavukSharma

Comment: it gives an Error , I updated the question and i will try reinstalling the Gradle may be my gradle files are corrupted @MorbiusBlack

Comment: The problem when you run the project first time it will download files from internet.  `C:\Users\Usernameof your pc\.gradle\wrapper\dists` delete all files in dist folder and run the project again.make sure you have some high speed connection it need to download some other files too. @BhavukSharma

Comment: Ok thanks @MobiusBlack i will try that

Comment: i removed the flutter and installed it from scratch and now there is no problem with it thanks a-lot everyone for your attention